# How to navigate horizontally

Tags: vim, navigation

Say, I have a (HAML/ruby) line that is being edited in Vim, like this:

```
%img{ src: (@image.presence || 'http://placehold.it/60x80/'), alt: "", data: { "snippet-image" => "image" "<150x<80"  alt="alt" />
```

I now need to remove `alt="alt" />` and replace that with `} }` turning the line into

```
%img{ src: (@image.presence || 'http://placehold.it/60x80/'), alt: "", data: { "snippet-image" => "image" "<150x<80" } }
```

I am at,for example, the first `{`. When I am have navigated to just before "alt=" I can replace that just fine, with `C} }`. The problem lies in efficiently getting to the `alt=` part.

- `13W`, count, or guess the amount of Words, and move that amount. This is very inefficient, it takes me nearly half a minute of pointing at my screen to count the thirteen words.
- `$2B`, move to the end of the line, move two Words back. In this very case, more efficient, but still requires counting, and breaks when I had to be at, say, the middle of the line.
- `/alt=<cr>h` Search for `alt=`. Then move one character backward. Again: works in this case, but this breaks when searching for more common things. For example I want to  move to the 14th `"`.

I think I am missing some simple modifier of concept to navigate more efficiently in horizontal direction, with long lines. Vertically, there are many things (text-objects) to navigate by, and there are helpers like relative-numbering. 
The example here is code. But I get the same kind of problems when navigating long paragraphs of text in a report or article.

How do you normally navigate horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with:

```
$vT";;c } }
```

Comment: You pointed me at `;` and `,'`, which I was nu aware of. It it pretty much the missing piece, indeed. *Repeat latest f, t, F or T [count] times.*

Answer (score 1):

I think at least part of the answer is that (at least in my opinion) long lines are a code smell; not just for the navigation problems you've brought up, but also because

- they are difficult to comprehend (visually, especially because different editors soft-break them differently)
- most tools have a line-based understanding of changes (e.g. when viewing diffs in source control), and long lines disrupt that (e.g. the "blame" output of who changed which line last).

Most languages / syntaxes allow to "break" lines (e.g. with the `\` line-continuation character in Bash, C, etc.), and I would advocate use of that to avoid such overly long lines as much as possible.

---

That said, I mostly stick to WORD-wise `W` movements to the (coarse) location, or alternatively `f` / `t` if there's a discernible unique `{char}` in the vicinity.

Comment: I agree fully that long lines are a code smell. In Code. When writing articles, long lines are not a smell, but simply a writing style. And even then: if you encounter a long line, and find that smelly, you might decide to refactor that. Which means, you have to navigate that line in order to refactor it. In other words: there are still many cases in which one has to navigate long lines horizontally and one wishes to do so efficiently.

Comment: In articles, paragraphs are usually (with `:set wrap`) soft-broken over multiple screen lines; I then use either `gj` / `gk`, or jump to the next sentence with `)`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `f<char>`/`F<char>` and then `;` till I get to the right place. If I see there are many instances of the character I go for some unique character nearby or fallback to `/` search command. It is also a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement to [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20586653/3047301) answer:

```
$3T"C } }
```

I had to leave a comment to an answer, but I didn't have enough reputation